Is glueball stable and why or why not?
I heard that the glueball can be a candidate for dark matter. Glueball is electric neutrality, which is fine, but is it stable? Is its lifetime longer than the universe? If it is true, what is the reason for it?
Or do I misunderstand something? The glueball for dark matter is not the glueball in QCD?

Nobody knows. Stable glueballs have, for sure, not been observed. That gives theorists a wide and imaginative field of ideas to hunt on. If they continue to be unobserved the interest in them will eventually disappear. Hunting a Snark is only fun if the Snark is not a (career) Boojum.

You have to work/speculate/contrive very hard to stabilize glueballs against decay to light mesons. Linked, and also, ......


Or do I misunderstand something? The glueball for dark matter is not the glueball in QCD?

You do misunderstand something: those glueballs tossed around in cosmology are not QCD  glueballs,  as conventional QCD glueballs are unstable to decay to light real-world mesons (pions, etc...).
Instead, the dark matter glueballs are those of   totally speculative "QCD-like" gauge theories, largely invented for that very purpose, immune to coupling to our world. Out of whole cloth.
